# Issue including post compile phase modifications in artifact deployed to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, activejdbc

I am developing a Spring MVC application using ActiveJDBC as my ORM, a Tomcat Server, and IntelliJ as my IDE.

For necessary functionality, ActiveJDBC requires some byte code manipulation -- called instrumentation by the ORM -- of compiled classes. So after the compile phase, static methods are added to the compiled classes. This is all fine, however when I try and deploy an artifact of my web application to Tomcat, the WAR contains the compiled classes *before* the byte manipulation (instrumentation) has occurred.

To include the compiled output post the instrumentation required by ActiveJDBC, I have tried:

Creating the artifact by navigating to File > Project Structure and then manually including the compiled class that included the methods added via instrumentation. 
[image]
Deploying the artifact described above results in the following error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

When I instead use the main module's compile output, I can access the application on the browser, but, receive a 500 error on pages where the source code calls methods that are made available with the instrumentation (a post compile task).

My questions:
1) For building an artifact to be deployed, is it required to use the compile output of the main module?
2) How do I include *post compile phase modifications* in the artifact if the artifact includes the compilation of the main module as is?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake! I forgot to use the appropriate directory structure when building the artifact manually.

Answer (score 0):

While you *could*  use IntelliJ Idea to deploy, almost nobody does this. Just use some of the examples from JavaLite projects: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example, and specifically a Maven Instrumentation Plugin: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L31 to instrument your models before packaging. After that, deploy a WAR file as usual. Building and packaging on command line will produce more consistent results than from an IDE.

Additionally, you might want to look into ActiveWeb for your web part: http://javalite.io/activeweb because it is nicely integrated with [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc).